# Sendy.co with postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, sendy

Does any one have any experience in linking **sendy.co to postgresql** database. I was trying to connect it updating include.php file but no luck for some reason. Went through the number of online resources and by the looks of things sendy is a MySQL only resource (atleast this is that a comment from a few years back says).

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.